# input ng-model within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am repeating a list of tasks that I would like other users to be able to comment on using an input field. I repeat the list with ng-repeat and am trying to send the value of the comment input to the server with ng-model and scope. I am testing by console logging but it shows as undefined. Please help!

Html:

```
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div ng-repeat='task in taskList' class="task">
    <div class="postedBy">
      <h6>{{task.user.userName}}</h6>
    </div>
    <h4>{{task.taskText}}</h4>
    <div class="comments">
        <input ng-model="newComment" type="text" placeholder="comments">
        <button ng-click='comment(task.taskId)' type="button" name="button">Add</button>
      <h6>{{task.commentText}}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS controller:

```
$scope.comment = function(id,text){
      console.log(`send comment text ${$scope.newComment}`);
      console.log(`task Id: ${id}`);
    };
```

This is the first time I've tried to do more than display itmes with ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because `ngRepeat` creates its own `$scope`.

Always assign `ngModel` using `Dot Rule` or `controller-as-syntax`.

Put it in your controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Then use the `ngModel` as this:

```
<input ng-model="model.newComment[$index]" type="text" placeholder="comments">
```

Then you can have something like this:

```
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div ng-repeat="task in taskList track by $index" class="task">
    <div class="postedBy">
      <h6>{{task.user.userName}}</h6>
    </div>
    <h4>{{task.taskText}}</h4>
    <div class="comments">
        <input ng-model="model.newComment[$index]" type="text" placeholder="comments">
        <button ng-click='comment($index)' type="button" name="button">Add</button>
      <h6>{{task.commentText}}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.comment = function(index) {
  console.log(`send comment text ${$scope.model.newComment[index]}`);
  console.log(`task Id: ${taskList[index].id}`);
};
```

**Note:** Your function is expecting 2 parameters, you should change it to:

```
$scope.comment = function(id) {
```

Comment: That helps, but it is not specific to the item in the repeat, meaning it changes the field for every task

Comment: I didn't understand.. what you said?

Comment: I took the second parameter out

Comment: And changed your `ngModel` as I said?

Comment: Remember to change it also => `console.log(\`send comment text ${$scope.model.newComment}\`);`

Comment: I need the input from a specific task, as of now it shows in all tasks input fields

Comment: just got back to work and tried it. had to change the task id part back, but it works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from @developer033. 
Here is what solved my problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="taskContainer">
  <div ng-repeat="task in taskList track by $index" class="task">
    <div class="postedBy">
      <h6>{{task.user.userName}}</h6>
    </div>
    <h4>{{task.taskText}}</h4>
    <div class="comments">
        <input ng-model="model.newComment[$index]" type="text" placeholder="comments">
        <button ng-click='comment(task.taskId,$index)' type="button" name="button">Add</button>
      <h6>{{task.commentText}}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$scope.model = {};
    $scope.comment = function(id, index) {
      console.log(`send comment text ${$scope.model.newComment[index]}`);
      console.log(`task Id: ${id}`);
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML,

```
<input ng-model="newComment" type="text" placeholder="comments">
<button ng-click='comment(task.taskId, newComment)' type="button" name="button">Add</button>
```

JavaScript,

```
$scope.comment = function(id, text) { 
  console.log(`task Id: ${id}`);
  console.log(`send comment text ${text}`);
};
```